# Orden descendente en Datatable usando datatable de boostrap

Tags: jquery, datatables

Quiero ordenar mis datos de manera descendente, pero no lo hace.

Este es el **script**

```
 <script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable({
      "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
      "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
    }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
      "responsive": true,
    });
  });
</script>
```

[enlace de referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175937/orden-descendente-en-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta agregando:

```
order: [[1, "desc"]],
```

Donde 1 es la posición de la columna y "desc" o "asc" es el orden que le daras a la misma.

Quedando:

```
$('#example2').DataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": false,
  "order": [[1, "desc"]], // Aqui la columna a ordenar
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": false,
  "responsive": true,
});
```

Puedes revisar la referencia:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Saludos :)